# How can I add bundle product group price?

Tags: magento

I want to add bundle product price for individual group. How can I do this?

thanks

Jitendra

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a 'Grouped product' instead of a 'Bundled product'. For a bundled product, without any serious coding, this is just not possible unless you are working with pricerules on the bundled product (with its caveats).

Answer (score 0):

issue solve my self as below step.

1) Create custom attribute from Manage Attributes like top, bottom

2) Create new product sets from Manage Attribute Sets  like bundle

3) Select which one create recently  attribute sets  and drag the attribute which in create in step 1

4) one radio.phtml file and add below code

```
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();;
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        if($attribute->bundle_top_price>0){  
            echo  $currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $currency_code )->getSymbol().'&nbsp;';
            if($_option->getTitle()=='top'){                  
                echo number_format($attribute->bundle_top_price,2);   
            }else {  
               echo number_format($attribute->bundle_bottom_price,2);   
            }
        }
```